# Clear Date Field

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to clear the selected date from the date field (using HTML and JavaScript). It is not clearing the field - when clicking on the button nothing happens - can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

HTML Code:

```
  <div class="leftField">
     <div class="formField50">
         <input id="txtAwarenessDate_date" type="text" class="readonly 
         textfield textfield35 required" readonly="readonly"
         title="Awareness Date" />
         <input id="btnAwarenessDateCalendar" type="button" 
         class="calendarImage" title="Awareness Date" />
     </div>
        <input id="awareClear" type="button" class="formButton115" 
         title="Click Clear Date" value="Clear Aware Date" 
         onclick="javascript:clearAwareDate();"/>
     </div>
   </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function clearAwareDate() {

    document.getElementById('txtAwarenessDate_date').value = "";    

 }
```

Comment: readonly attribute not allowing to give any input value

Comment: You can post the code as a runnable snippet, much easier to work with.

Comment: @user2181397—the [*readonly* attribute](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#the-readonly-attribute) only stops user entry via the UI, nothing else.

Comment: @RobG absolutely right but ,but If I create a fiddle and run this code I wiont be able to test since there i am not able to provide any input. Other than that it works fine

Comment: @user2181397—yes, the OP must be using code and listener on *btnAwarenessDateCalendar* to provide a date picker to set the value, but has not mentioned that.

Comment: @IreneS the HTML and script is all fine may be you are missing something  (validation lib.etc) find it out.

Comment: Since I am still new - I am not sure what is it and where to find validation lib.

Answer (score 1):

Try making it readonly false while executing onclick function and turn readonly to true.

```
function clearAwareDate() {
    document.getElementById("txtAwarenessDate_date").readOnly = false;
    document.getElementById('txtAwarenessDate_date').value = ""; 
    document.getElementById("txtAwarenessDate_date").readOnly = true;
}
```

Codepen URL for reference - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GqJbEZ

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work.  I am still new.  I use the calendar image with  css and javascript to have calendar function work.